# Why Java ArrayList's remove() method implementation does not decrease the size of internal array data?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For [`add()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29) method, the implementation is such that the [`elementData\[\]`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#111) array's size grows as needed. However, looking at the [`remove()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29) method, it does not shrink the size as elements are removed.

I tested using a simple code and the `elementData[]` starts out with `10` and grows. However, when I delete all the elements using `remove()` method, the size of `elementData[]` stays at the point where I finished adding all elements.

```
int testSize = 10000000;

ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// size of elementData[] is 10
for(int i = 0; i < testSize; i++) {
    alist.add(i);
}
// size of elementData[] is 13845150
for(int i = alist.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    alist.remove(i);
}
// size of elementData[] remains at 13845150
```

Isn't this wasting memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should note that the size of an array cannot be changed, once created. Changing the size of the underlying array of an `ArrayList` requires that the entire content of the array be copied to the new array.

When you are increasing the size, you must allocate a larger array, otherwise you could not fit in the new elements.
However, it's not worth the performance overhead to copy everything when you remove from the list. Memory is usually a lower concern than performance.